# How to error trap or error proof Sub Workbook_SheetChange for Pivot Table filters

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I could use some help with some error trapping for the following VBA code. This code very nicely controls 2 pivot tables filter values from a single cell value on a worksheet. The problem occurs when the value does not occur in the filter. I could use an elegant way to simply tell the user that the value does not exist for one or both of the Pivot Tables.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit 
Sub

Dim pt1 As PivotTable
Dim pt2 As PivotTable
Dim Field1 As PivotField
Dim Field2 As PivotField
Dim NewCat1 As String
Dim NewCat2 As String

Set pt1 = Worksheets("Lookup").PivotTables("PTProd")
Set Field1 = pt1.PivotFields("Material Number End")
NewCat1 = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2").Value

Set pt2 = Worksheets("Lookup").PivotTables("PTClaim")
Set Field2 = pt2.PivotFields("Material")
NewCat2 = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2").Value

With pt
Field1.ClearAllFilters
Field1.CurrentPage = NewCat1
pt1.RefreshTable
Field2.ClearAllFilters
Field2.CurrentPage = NewCat2
pt2.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many ways you can approach this.  Something like this should work for you.

```
Sub HandleError()
' Your code here

On Error GoTo ErrMsg

Exit Sub

ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("Type in your message here."), , "MESSAGE TITLE"

End Sub
```

Or . . .

```
MsgBox Err.Description
```

Comment: By replacing the "Sub Workbook_SheetChange()" with "Sub HandleError()" will the SheetChange function continue to work?

Comment: I don't see how that's going to work.  The event is a SheetChange event.  That's what fires off a certain process, which can be pretty much anything.  You can certainly use both together!